# Group a timestamp column by day and add a column with the first and a column with the last value from that day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2016-express

I have a timestamp table like this:

| t_stamp |
| --- |
| 2023-04-28 20:20:28.497 |
| 2023-04-28 20:00:27.940 |
| 2023-04-27 19:37:27.413 |
| 2023-04-27 16:55:26.817 |
| 2023-04-26 15:16:26.273 |
| 2023-04-26 12:04:25.753 |

I tried so far:

```
SELECT distinct [t_stamp] as Date
,max([t_stamp]) - min([t_stamp]) as DeltaTime
,max([t_stamp]) as First_Tstamp
,min([t_stamp]) as Last_Tstamp
  FROM [testdb]
  group by t_stamp
```

Trying to get the output containing the date, the delta time between the first and the last timestamp, and then the respective ones.
Like this:

| Date | DeltaTime | First_Tstamp | Last_Tstamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-28 | 00:20:28 | 2023-04-28 20:00:27 | 2023-04-28 20:20:28 |
| 2023-04-27 | 02:17:59 | 2023-04-27 16:55:26.817 | 2023-04-27 19:37:27 |
| 2023-04-26 | 03:11:01 | 2023-04-26 12:04:25.753 | 2023-04-26 15:16:26 |

but subtracting or using max() and min() always ends up in same value and in consequence, my Delta is always 0:

| Date | DeltaTime | First_Tstamp | Last_Tstamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-28 | 00:00:00 | 2023-04-28 20:20:28 | 2023-04-28 20:20:28 |
| 2023-04-27 | 00:00:00 | 2023-04-27 19:37:27 | 2023-04-27 19:37:27 |
| 2023-04-26 | 00:00:00 | 2023-04-26 15:16:26 | 2023-04-26 15:16:26 |

Comment: YOu need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` your `datetime` (it's not a `timestamp`, as `timestamp` in SQL Server is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value) in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`. Also putting a `DISTINCT` in your query makes little sense; your `GROUP BY` is already putting your results into *distinct* groups. The `DISTINCT` is only likely to be detrimental to the query's performance.